# unable to pass props to external const?

Tags: react-native

I am trying to create a "feed" of posts, similar to instagram/venmo/twitter. Each post is really a "Feed Cell", composed of components, displayed using a flat list. The actual "Feed Cell Class" imports each individual component, and composes the components into the post.

With this logic, I am trying to implement "Like" functionality, since this is a social networking app.

The flow goes like this:
User clicks the like button touchable opacity in the "Feed Cell Class"

```
           <TouchableOpacity 
                onPress={() => {
                    this.like(this.state.postID)
                }}> 
                        <Text style = {styles.tradeText}> like</Text>
            </TouchableOpacity>
```

which calls a function, "like", which is also in the "Feed Cell Class". Within this function, I call the "Like Post" imported function. I am passing the post ID to each of the functions.

```
import likePost from './FFCcomponents/likeButton'

like = async(postID) => {
    console.log(postID)
    likePost(postID);
}
```

Within the likeButton class, is the likePost function:

```
import React, { useState } from 'react'
import Firebase from '../../../firebase.js'

const likePost = ({ postID }) => {

    
    console.log(postID)
}

export default likePost;
```

However, the first postID prints, and the second one is "undefined".

```
P4Tu4GkcuxIZ9fGn1VFG
undefined
```

So the props are not passing correctly from the Feed Cell Class to the imported LikePost function. This is an issue, since all the building blocks are in their specific files, and are going to be imported to the Feed Cell Class to be composed into a post.

How can I fix this issue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why are you here doing async in the like function?

The problem may be related to the fact that you pass the object to the likepost function, and already likepost does distructorization.
Maybe you need to make `const likepost = (postID) => { ... }`

Comment: So instead of calling like, call likePost directly from the touchable opacity?

Comment: I tried calling likePost directly from the touchable opacity but it is still undefined.

Comment: hmm, i don't understand, try to remove the distructorization and do this: const likepost = (postid) => { ... }

Comment: Yep, so I passed the parameter (postID) directly to the function conducting the logic (likePost), and still get undefined. Before, I passed postID to the function "like", then called likePost and passed postID. neither are working.

Comment: Show again your code by function likepost

Comment: const likePost = ({ postID }) => {

    const likerUID = Firebase.auth().currentUser.uid;
    

    console.log(postID)
    console.log(likerUID)

Comment: just remove the curly braces in the function argument)Please do so - const likePost = (postID ) => ...